# Inaccessible propaganda poster on Bell Tower?

Tags: far-cry-4

How can you get to this poster? I tried jumping and spamming the action key (I'm on PC) and it didn't work. I tried dropping from the upper floor, can't get close enough to it.

[image: Unaccessible poster]

[image: Map position]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Throw a Molotov at the poster, and it Will burn.

Comment: Just smacked my forehead, so obvious.

Comment: It seems like a quarter of the posters are located in inaccessible spots. To take them down in addition to a Molotov and Fire Arrow, I believe some weapons like the Grenade and Rocket Launchers will also work. So you have option!

Comment: surprised no one has mentioned a flame thrower

Comment: You can also use your repair tool to set stuff on fire

Answer (score 9):

yep, like RussellM said - a Molotov; **or** a Fire Arrow.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a grenade launcher, M79 side arm or anything explosive (sticky c4) too.